# Get mail source using Zend_Mail

Tags: php, zend-framework, email, pop3, zend-mail

How can I get mail source (headers, body, boundary - all together as a plain text) using Zend_Mail (POP3).

It returns parsed parts by default, I need the raw message source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such method in Zend Mail.

But you may look at the class sources and see how to send a direct command to the mail server to get the message source.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use the `getRawHeader()` and `getRawContent()` methods of the `Zend_Mail_Storage_Pop3` class. Would it be enough for your purpose?

[Some API docs](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/_Mail_Storage_Pop3.html#%5CZend_Mail_Storage_Pop3) (I didn't find them in the Reference Guide):

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Zend_Mail instance, you can get the decoded content:

```
/** @var $message Zend_Mail */
echo $message->getBodyText()->getRawContent();
```

Answer (score 1):

I made my own layer for that:

```
    /**
 * Transport mail layer for retrieve content of message
 *
 * @author Petr Kovar
 */
class My_Mailing_Transport extends Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract{

    protected $_messageContent;

    /**
     * Only assign message to some variable
     */
    protected function _sendMail(){

        $this->_messageContent = $this->header . Zend_Mime::LINEEND . $this->body;
    }

    /**
     * Get source code of message
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMessageContent(){
        return $this->_messageContent;
    }

}
```

And than only call that:

```
$transport = new My_Mailing_Transport();
$transport->send($mail);
return $transport->getMessageContent();
```